# What are realistic numbers for the engineering/physics for a mag-lev train which would circumnavigate the entire planet earth?

Tags: physics, astrophysics, satellites

Suppose that you were writing a science-fiction novel (or movie script).

In the story, a giant magnetic-levitation (mag-lev) train encircles the entire planet earth.

The ring-shaped train track is located in low-earth orbit.

Although earth is not a perfect sphere, this ring-shaped train track is close to perfectly circular.

The train track is 13,400 kilometers in diameter.

The track is located roughly 329 kilometers above earth sea-level, but that varies a little-bit depending where on the train-track you are.

The train-track exists in the vacuum of space and there is no air-resistance.

If you painted a smiley face on the train-track, that smiley face would go around planet earth once every 1 hour 31 minutes and 6.6 seconds. That is, even if a train-car is stationary relative to the train-track, the train-track itself is spinning around planet earth.

Suppose that the train orbits above earth's equator. Maybe that is not the best location, but it is going to make it easier to talk about how fast the train is traveling.

When we measure the speed of the train, we are measuring it relative to the prime meridian (zero-degrees longitude). The speed of the train is not measured relative to the train track. Recall that the circle-shaped train track is 13,400 km in diameter. Thus, a passenger-car is traveling at 100 kilometers per hour if the passenger-car departs zero-degrees longitude, circles all of the way around the earth, and returns to zero-degrees longitude, after 134 hours.

Okay.... that was more context than I expected.
The follow are my actual ***questions***:

- How fast would a train-car have to travel (relative to the surface of planet earth) in-order for the centripetal force to feel to train passengers as if the passengers were walking on earth? Assume that the train track prevents the train-car from going into a higher orbit.
- Suppose that a passenger car is initially traveling 7.71 km/sec relative to the surface of planet earth. The passenger car is motion-less relative to the train-track. The train-car is initially accelerating at 1-g relative to earth's surface. Suppose that the train is engineered to ensure that the combination of centripetal force and train acceleration is always feels like 1 earth gravity to human passengers. Maybe the train car can tilt and swivel, so that the "ceiling" above passenger's heads is only tangent to earth's surface when the train is traveling at max-speed. How much time would pass untill 99% or more of the fake-gravity experienced by passengers on the train is due to centripetal force, and not the train accelerating along the track?
- Suppose that the train-car is traveling so fast along a ring in orbit around planet earth that the centripetal-force experienced aboard the passenger car feels like 1 earth gravity (or maybe 2 earth gravities total? 1g is needed to combat earth, and 1g for fake gravity aboard the train?)... anyway, how would time compare on the train to time on planet earth? 1 minute on the train equal 1.2 minutes on earth? Are we traveling at relativistic speeds at that point? Basically, there is 1-g of acceleration pulling the train into higher orbit, but the train is not allowed to move to a higher orbit, due to the train-track.

Comment: James Clerk Maxwell proved that solid rings around planets are unstable back in 1859. You're going to need something besides its rotation rate to keep any perturbation from resulting in the ring scraping the ground at 7 km/s.

Comment: This to me looks like 3+ questions in one post. You will likely get better results if you narrow it down to a smaller scope and ask subsequent questions separately. I'd pick one of the three points above and focus on it.

Comment: @notovny Would electrodynamic propulsion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodynamic_tether#Uses_for_ED_tethers) work to stabilise a ring like this?

Comment: How do you get on and off this train?

Comment: The train track doesn’t orbit — solid rings around a planet aren’t in orbit around that planet.

Comment: @MikeScott there is nothing solid in a 13k km diameter ring construction, whatever steel u use it is not enough, so the only way for it to be is to orbit.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do this Spiderman.

To the first question. The Acceleration duo to centripetal force is $$a_c = {v²\over r}$$ where $a_c$ is the Acceleration, $v²$ is the Momentary or Tangental Velocity and $r$  is the radius. We can rearrange this Formular to solve for $v$. $$\sqrt{a_c * r} = v$$ Givin the inital conditions, we now only need to put in one G as $a_c$ and Earths Radius for $r$ plus your height and we get the needed velocity.

Which turns out to be $8107 {m/s}$. So your train would have to travel slightly faster than Orbital Velocity which is around $7900 {m/s}$. That makes sense because what we Simulate is an Earth with a bigger Radius.

Now again, this means your train has to shoot along the Rail at $8.1 {km/ s}$ in order to be "pulled out" with a Force of $9.81 {m/ s²}$. That is pretty bloody fast.

Your 2nd Question is not really that hard. We know the Final Velocity, Acceleration so we only need time. I wont write down the formulars, just accept that it would take 13 Minutes at 1g to reach the Final Velocity.

To your first question, you have to keep in mind what the Forces are we are talking about. To talk in the space of Vectors, Earths Gravity as a Vectors is always pointing towards the Center. While the Ac vector always points away from earth. So there is no way, at least with this configuration, that the two add. Anyways, since we are in Orbit, we effectivly dont need to take earths gravity into account.

There are relativistic effects of course. But like, not a lot. First, how fast is the Train moving. Well approximently $16 {km/s}$. This Final Velocity is a composite from the Orbital Velocity (Which dosnt help us with the Centripital Force, the Orbital Velocity is basically just there to zero out Gravity from Earth) and the Centripital Force Velocity.

$16 {km/s}$ is very very fast. But not nearly fast enough.

The Formular for Timedilation is: $$t´ = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v²}{c²}}}$$ Where $t´$ is or dilated time, $t$ is or time step, or the Amount of time we want to look at, $v$ is or relative Velocity and $c$ is the Speed of light.

Long story short, for every secound that passes on Earth, 1.027 secounds pass on the Train.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that last part is backwards.  One second on the Train would be 1027 seconds on Earth.

Comment: Let me crunch the numbers on that... Yeah i f*ed up there. You are right D:

Comment: $1/\sqrt{1-(16/300{,}000)^2}$ is about 1.000000001, nowhere even close to 1.027.

Answer (score 1):

First to answer just the first question:

> How fast would a train-car have to travel (relative to the surface of planet earth) in-order for the centripetal force to feel to train passengers as if the passengers were walking on earth? Assume that the train track prevents the train-car from going into a higher orbit.

This is a special case.

Your track is orbiting at exactly orbital velocity for that height.
This is 8103 m/s

If your train moves *against* the track's direction, at exactly that same speed of 8103m/s, then relative to Earth it is standing still, and experiencing 1g of gravity towards Earth.
Except that it does not, because it is a bit further removed from the planet surface. g would be about 8.87924m/s2, which is 90.42% of normal gravity.
This is as high as you can get the apparent gravity towards the planet to go.

Let's try running the train in the opposite direction, along the orbit of the track, speeding it up.
We want 9.81m/s2 of outward centrifugal effect. In addition to the presupplied force from track orbit.
9.81 + 8.87924 = 18.68924m/s2
This requires orbital speed at that height of 11190m/s (total)
subtract the "free" speed supplied by the track of 8103m/s = **3087m/s train speed relative to track.**

This **will provide a centripetal effect 'gravity force' of exactly 9.81m/s2** away from the planet.

Your friends for this question are the calculators for
[Centrifugal Effect](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/centrifugal-force)
and [Gravity at a distance](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/gravitational-force)

---

As for the time relativity question?
It is actually a lot more complicated than just the speed.
You have a time dilation due to moving at 11190m/s of about 22 seconds per 100 years. (31540000022 seconds per observer 31540000000 ) [Time Dilation Calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/time-dilation)

But you also have gravity affecting time.
By being on earth surface, only 6 371 km from its mass, your timerate is altered by a factor of -4.464422509e-3 [Gravity time dilation calculator](https://www.engineersedge.com/calculators/gravitational_time_dilation_15003.htm)
The train, by being at a greater distance, is only experiencing timerate alteration of -4.464422544e-3 , a difference of 3.5e-11
By being on the ground, your time is moving slower. By 1.1039 seconds per 100 years

So, the fancy-pants answer is that by getting on that train and circling the orbiting track fast enough to plaster you on the ceiling at 1g, you are experiencing time slower by a rate of (22-1.1039 = 20.96 seconds) per century

Comment: Now a honest poll. how many of you remembered that time slows down when you are in a gravity well?

Comment: Never forget, always in mind, thinking that day and night, lol

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to answer your question as is, due to the fairly critical issue that a ring around the world like that is inherently unstable and will crash in relatively short order.

What you need, then, is a kind of actively stabilised megastructure which is rather boringly called an [Orbital Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_ring). The structure does not itself orbit, but is rather stationary with respect to the surface of the Earth and has a number of tethers or towers that connect it to the surface. Inside the structure is an electromagnetic track that accelerates a continuous stream of projectiles around the ring. The centripetal force exerted by the projectiles on the magnets gives the structure its shape, and holds it up above the Earth.

(this is a very brief and rather poor summary; you should perhaps read the slightly less inadequate wiki page linked above which references the original papers, the first of which you can find [here](https://www.orionsarm.com/fm_store/OrbitalRings-I.pdf)).

Now you have a more-or-less plausible structure to attatch your actual train track to, and your questions can perhaps be answered.

---

> How fast would a train-car have to travel (relative to the surface of planet earth) in-order for the centripetal force to feel to train passengers as if the passengers were walking on earth?

Note that I'm using a track radius of 6700km (which I assume is the figure you intended for convenience) , and assuming the track is circular.

At a mere 329km up, the strength of Earth's gravity is still about 90% of what it is at sea level (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Altitude) for relevant equation). This means that with the train stationary, passengers may notice some difference, but they will quickly acclimatise.

In order to *increase* the apparent strength of gravity, you'd need to move your train fast enough to provide centrifugal artificial gravity, where "down" would appear to be *away* from the Earth. To provide a whole 1g, you need to have ~18.7g centripetal acceleration to overcome Earth's natural gravity and provide enough extra.

There's some handy spun gravity equations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity). The useful one here is $a = R(\frac{2\pi}{T})^2$, where $a$ is the apparent acceleration, $R$ is the radius of the loop and $T$ is the time taken to do one full revolution. One can see that the rotational period required to produce a net 1g centripetal acceleration in a loop 329km above the Earth's surface is ~3761 seconds, giving a required speed of ~11.19km/s. Note that this is *above* escape velocity for this altitude (~10.9km/s), so anything falling out of the train is going to be flung into interplanetary space.

> Suppose that a passenger car is initially traveling 7.71 km/sec relative to the surface of planet earth. The passenger car is motion-less relative to the train-track.

The nature of *my* track is rather different to yours, so I'll consider the train being stationary relative to the surface of the Earth to start with.

> Suppose that the train is engineered to ensure that the combination of centripetal force and train acceleration is always feels like 1 earth gravity to human passengers... How much time would pass untill 99% or more of the fake-gravity experienced by passengers on the train is due to centripetal force, and not the train accelerating along the track?

Initially, velocity will be 0, therefore centripetal acceleration will be 0, but acceleration due to gravity will be about .9g. The train's acceleration will therefore be something like

$$a_{tr} = g_n - \left| \frac{v_t^2}{R} - g_0 \right|$$

where $v_t$ is the train's velocity, $R$ is the radius of the track, $g_n$ is standard Earth gravity and $g_0$ is gravity at 329km up. This is a less-than-friendly differential equation, and as such I'm quite unable to do nice symbolic integration for you to get a nice velocity- or acceleration-given-time equation, so I've just brute forced it (the technical term for this is "solved numerically")

At some velocity $v_b = \sqrt{Rg_0}$, centripetal acceleration and gravitational acceleration will balance, and the train's forward acceleration will peak at 1g. This is ~7.7km/s (which is orbital speed at this altitude, not coincidentally). It will take the train something like 3356 seconds to reach this speed from a standing start.

To reach the point where centrifugal forces are providing ~0.99g pull away from the Earth will take 4384 seconds from stationary, or 1478 seconds from orbital speed, which I *think* gives you the number you originally were interested in.

It travels along ~19% of the track between a standing start and reaching $v_b$, and ~55% of the track between a standard start and reaching cruising speed.

> Are we traveling at relativistic speeds at that point?

If you were running GPS satellite replacements on your train you'd need to think about relativistic corrections, but for everything else the effects are just too miniscule to care about.